# How to make code smaller by using loop to print player name and the ring game

Tags: python

If tosses = 4  output shows two peg toss point for user and if tosses = 5, output shows one peg toss point for user. Also, how do I put these blockquotes because when I put any test code inside that it says the code is not formatted properly.

'''

```
import random
question = 0
correct = 5
points = 0
tosses = random.randint(3, 5)
utotal = 0
upoint = 0
cpoint = 0
ctotal = 0
user = "Adarsh"
print(user,"s turn")
while tosses <= correct :
    peg = random.randint(0, 5)
    tosses = tosses + 1
    if peg == 0 :
        upoint = - 15
        utotal = utotal - 15
    elif peg == 1 :
        upoint = 20
        utotal = utotal + 20
    elif peg == 2 :
        upoint = 50
        utotal = utotal + 50
    elif peg == 3 :
        upoint = 10
        utotal = utotal + 10
    elif peg == 4 :
        upoint = 30
        utotal = utotal + 30
    elif peg == 5 :
        upoint = 100
        utotal = utotal + 100
    print("Ring is on Peg", peg, ".", "+", upoint)
print("total points", utotal)
print("Computer's turn")
for i in range(0, 4):
    peg = random.randint(0, 5)
    tosses = tosses + 1
    if peg == 0 :
        cpoint = - 15
        ctotal = ctotal - 15
    elif peg == 1 :
        cpoint = 20
        ctotal = ctotal + 20
    elif peg == 2 :
        cpoint = 50
        ctotal = ctotal + 50
    elif peg == 3 :
        cpoint = 10
        ctotal = ctotal + 10
    elif peg == 4 :
        cpoint = 30
        ctotal = ctotal + 30
    elif peg == 5 :
        cpoint = 100
        ctotal = ctotal + 100
    print("Ring is on Peg", peg, ".", "+", cpoint)
print("total points", ctotal)
if ctotal > utotal:
    print("computer wins")
else:
    print("you win")
```

'''
[testCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2ZDr.jpg)

Comment: When you are saying “when I put any test code inside”, do you mean that you are putting the messages in the image? Those are not Python commands! In general I think you should study how to create a method called ‘toss’, where you can input the player name and the method will do the tossing for you. Right now you’re basically repeating the same code twice ...

Comment: I thought blockquote is to add some clarifications, which is what I wanted to do so that way I don't have to link the screenshot. also can u link the method toss because I only seem to be getting coin toss program, I don't see any coding in it, that could be the solution to my issue. also, yeah, I repeated the code to show output because I don't know how to achieve that desired output in a more optimized way by using loops and sentinel values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script below should give approximately what you wanted. Have defined a method `toss(user, tosses)` that takes the `user` and `tosses` as parameters. `user` is a user name and `tosses` is the *same* number of tosses, in order to run the experiment on equal terms.

```py
import random
# The commented lines below are not used
# question = 0
correct = 5
points = 0
#upoint = 0 -- again not used
#cpoint = 0

def toss(user, tosses):
    print(user,"s turn")
    upoint = total_points = 0 # Initialize so that they can be used below 
    while tosses <= correct :
        peg = random.randint(0, 5)
        tosses = tosses + 1
        if peg == 0 :
            upoint = - 15
            total_points = total_points - 15
        elif peg == 1 :
            upoint = 20
            total_points = total_points + 20
        elif peg == 2 :
            upoint = 50
            total_points = total_points + 50
        elif peg == 3 :
            upoint = 10
            total_points = total_points + 10
        elif peg == 4 :
            upoint = 30
            total_points = total_points + 30
        elif peg == 5 :
            upoint = 100
            total_points = total_points + 100
        print("Ring is on Peg", peg, ".", "+", upoint)
    print("total points", total_points)
    return(total_points)

# moved the tosses' initialisation here before we call
# the corresponding methods

tosses = random.randint(3, 5)
utotal = toss("Arash", tosses)
ctotal = toss("Computer", tosses)

# Your comment can perhaps be placed here
if ctotal > utotal:
    print("computer wins")
else:
    print("you win")
```

An example run

```
Arash s turn
Ring is on Peg 4 . + 30
Ring is on Peg 3 . + 10
Ring is on Peg 2 . + 50
total points 90
Computer s turn
Ring is on Peg 2 . + 50
Ring is on Peg 3 . + 10
Ring is on Peg 5 . + 100
total points 160
computer wins
```

NOTE: Your link that you call *blockquote* shows the program execution. If I understand well, you were thinking of putting that as a *comment* somewhere in your script, probably towards the end, where the printing takes place.